# Punctuation mark is missing in Digital Millennium Copyright Act help page

Tags: bug, help-center

The first paragraph is missing a punctuation mark in the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA) Takedowns help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dmca-takedown). Could you please add the necessary punctuation?

In plain text:

> The [Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) is a United States copyright law that Stack Exchange abides by. Per the act, the company needs to remove copyrighted content that infringes the holder's rights when notified of its existence on our platform. DMCA Takedown requests are how copyright holders inform us of its existence

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Punctuation mark is missing]

Comment: Here is a link to the [DMCA](https://www.copyright.gov/legislation/dmca.pdf) which IMHO is better than Wikipedia.